# scrollToRowAtIndexPath - inconsistent behavior

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an NSObject class ("Reel") that implements the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource and has a UITableView property called reelView:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *reelView;
```

In my Main view controller ("MainVC"),I have a UITableView that is controlled by Reel and the table displays just fine.

But when I try to programmatically scroll to a specific row, I get different results depending on where I call the method.

If I call the method on its own:

```
- (void)spin:(id)sender {

[self.reelView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

}

nothing happens.

But when I put this exact same line of code in the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which is executed when a row in the table is selected, then the table scrolls the way I would expect it to.  To be clear, I'm not calling:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

but instead

```
[self.reelView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

in the delegate method.

It behaves the same way in the simulator and on an actual iPad.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to `NSLog( @"%@", self.reelView );` in both places and make sure that they point to the same object. I suspect they do not.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I set breakpoints and in the spin: method, self.reelView points to nil; in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method it points to a valid object.  I've used both weak and strong in the declaration of reelView and it doesn't make a difference.  I've also checked to see if the reference to self.reelView persisted after I selected a row, but it doesn't.

Comment: As a workaround, I pulled reelView - the UITableView object - out of the Reel object and put it in MainVC.  With the reference to reelView in MainVC and executing the scrollToRowAtIndexPath: method in MainVC, it works.  Not as elegant and as encapsulated as I would like, but it works.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Techniques for encapsulation seems like is deserves to be the topic for a whole different question.